# Can IoC frameworks make objects with dynamic constructor parameters?

Tags: java, node.js, inversion-of-control

Here is how to set up Pico Container with Java:

```
public class Juicer {  
 private final Peelable peelable;  
 private final Peeler peeler;  

 public Juicer(Peelable peelable, Peeler peeler) {  
 this.peelable = peelable;  
 this.peeler = peeler;  
 }  
}
```

Configure:

```
MutablePicoContainer pico = new DefaultPicoContainer(); 
pico.addComponent(Apple.class);  /* Apple is peelable */
pico.addComponent(Juicer.class);  
pico.addComponent(Peeler.class);
```

Use!

```
Juicer juicer = (Juicer) pico.getComponent(Juicer.class);
```

In this case Juicer will create its own Apple and Peeler.

This is insanely the opposite of how `node-di` works. node-di will create one object then cache it and keep using it - so it's much better for resource management (e.g. one connection pool).

What I don't understand how to do is instantiate it where the, e.g., Apple class is more dynamic. Perhaps its constructor is `Apple(BigDecimal price)` and when it's instantiated I need to pass the price. More realistically I have a hundred thousand users connecting on one machine, each with a different `PasswordAuthenticator`. How can `PasswordAuthenticator` come from the IoC framework when obviously a different one with different parameters needs to be given for each user?

A use of `PasswordAuthenticator` with IoC but without a framework is:

User.java:

```
// constructor
public User(String email, PasswordAuthenticator pa) {
    this.email = email;
    this.pa = pa;
```

PasswordAuthenticator.java:

```
public PasswordAuthenticator(byte[] privateKey, byte[] encryptedPassword) {
    // set instance variables
}
public String decrypt() {
    // crypto magic
    return decryptedPassword;
}
```

So of course you instantiate a user like:

```
User user = new User("abc@gmail.com", new PasswordAuthenticator(myKey, sqlResultSet.getBytes());
// sqlResultSet is for emphasis; to emphasize this is dynamic on a per-user basis
```

Now I must tell the container that it in fact *can not* instantiate PasswordAuthenticator's willy-nilly, but it can only do so when it is passed dynamically the arguments.

node-di is my target use case here so I'm tagging as both java and node. Obviously I'm trying to learn by analogy, and within the confines of what problems IoC frameworks can actually solve.

Comment: `How can PasswordAuthenticator come from the IoC framework when obviously a different one with different parameters needs to be given for each user` I don't know Pico at all, but for other IoC containers (I'm thinking Spring), you can specify a scope for the object being injected. You can have it create a new instance every time it's requested, with different arguments. Can you give an example of a few different `PasswordAuthenticator` objects that would need to be injected? How would you do it without IoC?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis added non-framework code; please see edit.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis also that sounds like what I want. Wouldn't be surprised if Spring has this and others don't but I haven't learned Spring's yet.

Comment: Do you want the container to create and process the `User` and `PasswordAuthenticator` objects because they have other injection targets/lifecycle methods it can manage? (Sorry, I may be slow in responding.)